# How to create a copy of a file after observing the event using File Listener (watchdog) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, watchdog, python-watchdog

I have below code which is listening to any `excel` file in one my directory. Below code is working file. However, I would like to modify the code such that as soon as new file arrives in the path it creates a copy of the same file in another folder. Let's say folder name is "today". I am not sure how to create a copy of same file as soon as new event is observed ? The copied file should be of same extension. In this case it will be `excel`

I am new to `OOP` so any help is much appreciated!

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer  
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
import time

class FileWatcher(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.xlsx"] 

    def process(self, event):
        
       # event.src_path will be the full file path
       # event.event_type will be 'created', 'moved', etc.
       print('{} observed on {}'.format(event.event_type, event.src_path))

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obs = Observer() 
    obs.schedule(FileWatcher(), path='path/')
    print("Monitoring started....")
    obs.start() # Start watching

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ob.stop()

    obs.join()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why this is a problem. But if I understand correctly, you only need to

```
import os, shutil
```

and in

```
def on_created(self, event):
    self.process(event)
    destination = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'today', event.src_path.split('\\')[-1])
    shutil.copyfile(event.src_path, destination)
```

if you want "today" to be a subfolder of your curernt script's working directory. If not set the path to something else

**UPDATE**

**Problem 1**: Pausing the watchdog, wasn't so hard. It queues consequtive triggers (Events) and executes them

**Problem 2**: The trigger is executed, when the file is created. That doesn't mean the OS is finished writing it, hence the I/O Exception when trying to access / copy it. You have to wait for the file to be completely written. The EventHandler has no means of telling, so you have to implement a workaround. I have added the code below, that should do the trick.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer  
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
import time, os, shutil

class FileWatcher(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.xlsx"] 

   def process(self, event):
        
        # event.src_path will be the full file path
        # event.event_type will be 'created', 'moved', etc.
        print('{} observed on {}'.format(event.event_type, event.src_path))

    def on_created(self, event):
        self._is_paused = True
        
        # WAITING FOR FILE TRANSFER
        file = None
        while file is None:
            try:
                file = open(event.src_path)
            except OSError:
                file = None                    
                time.sleep(1) # WAITING FOR FILE TRANSFER
                continue
        
        self.process(event)
        destination = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'today', event.src_path.split('\\')[-1])
        shutil.copyfile(event.src_path, destination)        
        self._is_paused = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    obs = Observer() 
    obs.schedule(FileWatcher(), path='.\\')
    print("Monitoring started....")
    obs.start() # Start watching

    try:
        while obs.isAlive():
            obs.join()
    finally:
        obs.stop()
        obs.join()
```

Comment: Thank you. I am having issue with copying multiple files..One file works great, but when I try to load multiple files to the source. I received permission error. Note. I change shutil.copyfile to shutil.copy to copy multiple files.. Any work around for it ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well one workaround would be to increase the "idle" time in your endless loop. Depending on the size of the excel files and the speed your harddrive is writing 100ms may be sufficient. I tried with `time.sleep(100)` instead of `time.sleep(1)` and it copies 2 files (rather small) to "today" with `shutil.copyfile`, since you get a watchdog trigger for every file individually

Comment: Another approach would be to suspend the watchdog while you're executing the copy process, depending on whether or not the watchdog trigger remains valid for the 2nd...3rd..etc. file while suspended and fires after resuming the watchdog operation. This is true for most embedded systems, not sure about the python library tho, but I would imagine it can be done as well. I will try and let you know

Comment: Thank you. I liked the 2nd approach, the reason being I am not sure how big will the files be when I try to execute the copy process .

Comment: It needed a few tweaks, I am explaining the reasons under "UPDATE"

Comment: Thank you worked liked charm! Little bit off topic question. I would like to log my print statements into txt file for this I am using below code after if__name__=='__main__'. But It's not logging the print statements into txt file. The txt file is empty. Not sure what is the issue ? Thanks! The code I am using is     logging.basicConfig(
        handlers=[RotatingFileHandler('./my_log.log', maxBytes=100000, backupCount=10)],
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s",
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')